# how to display the result of a DateTimePicker in a label

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, datetimepicker

good morning
I have the following code for a DateTimePicker, and I would like that when I press on the button, the date is shown in the Label (result), could you help me?

DateTimePicker works inherit a xamarin ContentView instead of just an Entry, xamarin and then creates the Stacklayout which xamarin add the Entry and the date and time xamarin pickers to content.

```
public class DateTimePicker2 : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {       

public  Entry Fecha { get; private set; } = new Entry() { TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center }; 
        public DatePicker DatePicker { get; private set; } = new DatePicker() { MaximumDate = DateTime.Today, IsVisible = false };
        public TimePicker TimePicker { get; private set; } = new TimePicker() { IsVisible = false };
        string stringFormat { get; set; }
        public string StringFormat { get { return stringFormat ?? "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"; } set { stringFormat = value; } }
        public DateTime DateTimed
        {
            get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateTimeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DateTimeProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("DateTime"); }
        }

        private TimeSpan Time
        {
            get
            {
                return TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTimed.Ticks);
                
            }
            set
            {
                DateTimed = new DateTime(DateTimed.Date.Ticks).AddTicks(value.Ticks);

            }
        }

        private DateTime date
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTimed.Date;
            }
            set
            {
                DateTimed = new DateTime(DateTimed.TimeOfDay.Ticks).AddTicks(value.Ticks);
            }
        }

        BindableProperty DateTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker2), DateTime.Now, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: DTPropertyChanged);

        public DateTimePicker2()
        {
            BindingContext = this;

            Content = new StackLayout()
            {
                Children =
            {
                DatePicker,
                TimePicker,
                Fecha
            }
            };

          
            TimePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) => Time = TimePicker.Time;
            DatePicker.Focused += (s, a) => UpdateEntryText();

            GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command = new Command(() => DatePicker.Focus()) });
            Fecha.Focused += (sender, args) => { Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DatePicker.Focus()); };
            DatePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) => { Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { TimePicker.Focus(); date = DatePicker.Date; UpdateEntryText();}); };
        }

        private void UpdateEntryText()
        {
            Fecha.Text = DateTimed.ToString(StringFormat);
             


        }

        static void DTPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var timePicker = (bindable as DateTimePicker2);
             timePicker.UpdateEntryText();
             
        }
    }
```

in Xaml it is used like this

```
         <local:DateTimePicker2    ></local:DateTimePicker2>
         <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"> </Button>
         <Label x:Name="result"></Label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign a name to your control

```
<local:DateTimePicker2 x:Name="dt2" />
<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
<Label x:Name="result" />
```

then in your handler

```
protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  result.Text = dt2.Datetimed.ToString();
}
```